# [mono]Arabic text rendering in linux / monodevelop 2.6

Tags: text, mono, monodevelop, arabic, xubuntu

I've been instructed to port a .NET/C# Windows application to linux (XUbuntu 11.10 or SliTaz 4). This application should be capable of rendering Arabic texts in part or all of its texts.

I managed to modify the Windows application so that it properly shows Arabic texts. I had to switch UseCompatibilityText to true.

When in linux, I tried to look for the same property. No luck. Is it a question of being using an old version of Mono? Is it something not yet supported?

Is there any way around this issue?
Thanks a lot in advance!
Antonio

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm new to MonoDevelop, but I saw your posting, and I have to say that when I tried to use Arabic in an "entry" box as a quick test, I had no trouble. This MD is straight out of the box, I didn't have to do anything other than coding and grab a small piece of Arabic text. I am using MD 2.8.8.6 on my mac.

Oops, let me check the same on my Linux box. I am using Kubuntu 12.04, and MD 2.8.6.3, and the same test above works. I'm not sure what exactly isn't working on yours, maybe my test is not extensive enough, or maybe you want to upgrade your version?

Cheers